# execute mongo request in a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I stock request in an array like :

```
tab = {
    request = People.find({$or: [{name: "test"}, {firstname: "test"}]});
}
```

How can I execute this request in "tab.request" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with fetch:

```
tab = {
    request : People.find({$or: [{name: "test"}, {firstname: "test"}]}).fetch();
}
```

The other thing is when you build stuff in `{}` you use `:` instead of `=` to match key value pairs

I hope this is right its for a request for JSON? If it is then it'll work